# How can I make an embedded Vimeo video not play after the first visit to my site?

Tags: vimeo

How can I make an embedded Vimeo video not play after the first visit to my site?

Answer (score 0):

I would create a cookie, and then check for that cookie within the embed code and set it to not autoplay if the cookie exists.

Another option is to check by IP, but that can be spotty, especially with dynamic IPs, and places like coffee shops and libraries with open wifi.